# Array into function (export xls file)

Tags: php, html

I do not understand how to pass all the ARRAY within all the columns in order to export them as an xls file.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
<a href='".site_url('main_page/EXPORT')
```

Take a look:

I am fetching all the different rows from a table and they are displayed in the screen, check it out (it does work) - this part is inside **page_view** (VIEW folder):

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">

    <h2 align="center">TABLE: USERS</h2>

        <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="table">
            <thead>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>user</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>lastname</th>
                <th>type</th>
                <th>status</th>
                <th>date</th>
            </thead>
```

```
<?php

    if (count($records) > 0 && $records != false)
     { 

        foreach($records as $record) {
        echo "<tr> 
    <td>".$record['id']."</td> 
    <td>".$record['username']."</td> 
    <td>".$record['name']."</td> 
    <td>".$record['lastname']."</td> 
    <td>".$record['type']."</td> 
    <td>".$record['status']."</td> 
    <td>".$record['date']."</td> 

    </tr>"; 
    }
    }

?>
```

Take a look at this (this is probably wrong)

```
echo "<tr> 
<td>".$record['id']."</td> 
<td>".$record['username']."</td> 
<td>".$record['name']."</td> 
<td>".$record['lastname']."</td> 
<td>".$record['type']."</td> 
<td>".$record['status']."</td> 
<td>".$record['date']."</td> 
<a href='".site_url('main_page/EXPORT')."/$record->id'> //THIS IS POBABLY WRONG
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EXPORT</button></a>
</tr>"; 

    </tbody>
```

Then, I want to pass that information inside this function:

```
public function EXPORT(){

        $data['records']=$this->MODEL->EXPORT_XLS();
        $this->load->view('page_view',$data);
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Create one more `td` and put __export__ link in it. On export page check for id and get data from database. Then put this data into xls-file.

Comment: Thank you for replying @u_mulder . I was thinking about something like this:
header('Content-Type: application/xls');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls');

How would you do it?

Comment: Where's the code to generate an Excel file?

Comment: you need to specify what framework or cms you are using because what you are trying to do is specific to the tool you are using